# C++11 how to observe memory order in atomic::store and atomic::load

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic

**Update 3**:
After understanding what "memory order" is, I know the problem is totally not related to compiler.
And yes, because my CPU architecture is Intel x86, **no matter what code I write, the memory order effect will never happen**.

**Update 2**:
I check the disassembly code. However, I find no matter how I add code, the x.store always prior to y.store.
The problem should come from compiler (which doesn't reorder these code) instead of CPU (as far as I think).

**Update**:
After I read comments, it seems like I have to borrow a machine which's CPU is alpha, arm or ppc.
Does anyone know where I can use this kind of machine even this is not for free?

Origin:
I am testing the code below.

```
atomic<int> x(0);
atomic<int> y(0);

void thr1()
{
    x.store(1,memory_order_relaxed);
    y.store(1,memory_order_relaxed);
}

void thr2()
{
    while(!y.load(memory_order_relaxed))
        ;
    cout<<x.load(memory_order_relaxed)<<endl;   //may 0 or 1
}
```

I know the output may be 0.
However, no matter how much times I tried, I always get 1.
Is this because of my CPU is x86 architecture?

If not, how to fix this problem?
(BTW, I know CppMem. But it cannot use loop.)

Comment: Maybe try http://www.1024cores.net/home/relacy-race-detector/rrd-introduction?

Comment: If you don't have hardware that has sufficiently relaxed ordering, you may not be able to see this. Can you run this on a DEC Alpha or a Playstation?

Comment: I'm not sure if this could make any difference but it seems likely that both numbers reside closely together in memory, very likely on the same page. Maybe you'll see different outcomes if you put them onto different pages.

Comment: x86's ordering is strong enough that you won't see `0` ever unless the compiler actively messes with you.

Comment: I will check RRD soon. Sorry, I don't have other hardware to test this code.

Comment: To T.C., so, I cannot observe the behavior of what I want until I change a platform?

Comment: Is there an emulator or virtual machine to test these things?

Comment: ARM is a bit more relaxed than x86 or X64 - probably the most accessible alternative architecture to try.

Comment: x86 provides TSO by default (ie unless you explicitly use nontemporal stores). Thus, you will never see reordering here. I doubt you'll see it on other architectures either, at least in such a simple program.

Comment: Your `x` and `y` are likely on the same cache line. Add some padding between them to reduce that likelihood. That still won't guarantee a different outcome.

Comment: @Jeff Your statement is incorrect, this is a common misconception. See http://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/cpu-cache-flushing-fallacy.html and longer https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~pes20/weakmemory/x86tso-paper.tphols.pdf

Answer (score 3):

What you are experiencing is not a "problem". At least, not as far as the standard is concerned.

When ordering is relaxed, this only means that ordering is no longer guaranteed. This does not mean that implementations *must* put them into different orders.

A different compiler may show it; then again, it may not. Hell, just changing the optimization might cause it to happen. Then again, maybe not. There is ultimately nothing you can do to *guarantee* seeing the other order (outside of emulation of some sort or similar tools). Just because you state that something *might* be possible does not ensure that it will or must happen.

Comment: As far as I understand memory ordering, _compiler_ is allowed to reorder subject stores should it decide it better for some reason. In that case it'd be possible to observe this 'weakness' even on x86. But I can't catch this with GCC and Clang. They reorder non-atomic stores, or even batch them using SIMD. But once I make variables atomic, stores become regular moves in order.

Comment: @ConstantinBaranov: There are two questions there: whether the compiler can put the instructions in a different order and whether the *hardware* will execute them in the specified order. If the compiler doesn't see a need to put them in a different order, then it won't. Further, just because the instructions come in a different order doesn't mean you can see it without emulation or other deep debugging.